# Pytorch Data Wont Fit in Memory - Example?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to find an example of training in Pytorch in batch from data on disk - akin to the Keras fit_generator. How would I alter the code below to read the csv from disk instead of loading it to memory?

I have found that one can iterate over a custom data loader like below, but I am unsure how to do this without loading all the data in memory.

I would like to:

- Train and validate the model with data held on disk
- Use mini-batches of the full data on disk
- Repeat x epochs

  class testLoader(Dataset):

  ```
        def __init__(self):

              #regular old numpy
              boston = load_boston()
              x=boston.data
              y=boston.target

              self.x = torch.from_numpy(x)
              self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)


              self.length = x.shape[0]
              self.vars =x.shape[1]

        def __getitem__(self, index):

            return self.x[index], self.y[index]

        def __len__(self):
            return self.length


  training_samples=testLoader()
  train_loader = utils_data.DataLoader(training_samples, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
  ```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: So the question is how to read data from disk in that data loader paradigm. How is this a bad question?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Comment: I don't know much about `.csv` files, but there is a discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-dataset-larger-than-memory/37785/9). Apparently you could use `pd.read_csv` using the `chunksize` argument.